# EXT-X-KEY HLS on AVPlayer iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming

i'm trying to get my AVPlayer read a HLS HTTP Encryption m3u8 playlist but it doesnt seems to work at all.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:2078799
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="mykey"
#EXTINF:9.009,
248_1_2078799.ts?m=1492793899
#EXTINF:9.009,
248_1_2078800.ts?m=1492793899
#EXTINF:9.009,
248_1_2078801.ts?m=1492793899
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="mykey2aftersegment"
#EXTINF:9.009,
248_1_2078802.ts?m=1492793899
#EXTINF:9.009,
248_1_2078803.ts?m=1492793899
#EXTINF:9.009,
248_1_2078804.ts?m=1492793899
```

My AVPlayer doesnt recognize that there's a Header of EXT-X-KEY in it. So what i tried is, to change the scheme of the playlist to access of my delegate method

```
func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool { 


}
```

But now, i have no clue what i should do. You guys have any ideas?